# Organize GIS data software: find identical, find versions of a shapefile, report on the map

Tags: windows, gis

I have many shapefiles, .mdb, .gdb and also .mxd, .lyr and ...

Many of this data have same share of data or they are identical

I want a software that can search, organize and then report this:

Identical GIS data

Same share of data (find a versions of one data)

Report on the map

How can I find this software?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What OS should it run on? What is your price limit (how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid software)?

Comment: Thank you,  OS: windows 10,  I want to know if free one or paid version exist.